# Converting .shp file to .csv file using ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, csv, ogr2ogr

I want to covert the .shp file to .csv file by using ogr2ogr
and I am running

```
PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8 ogr2ogr -f CSV "/home/pj/Desktop/test1.csv" "/home/pj/Desktop/20160705102900718.shp"
```

but the shell prompt

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open /home/pj/Desktop/20160705102900718.shx or /home/pj/Desktop/20160705102900718.SHX.
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/home/pj/Desktop/20160705102900718.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> GMT
  -> SQLite
  -> DODS
  -> ODBC
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shapefile consists of a bunch of files. The .shp and .shx are mandatory, .dbf and .prj are necessary for some tasks as well.

The error message notes that the .shx file for your .shp file is missing. If you rename the .shp file to match the naming conventions, make sure to rename the .shx file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your shapefile name. You need to rename your shapefile to start with letters because shapefiles cannot start with numbers.

Comment: no,when I rename my shapefile to test.shp,it is prompt this error too